# EF6 MVC5 Setting a 1-1 Relationship

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have got my application up and running using Code first, I am trying to set a 1-1 relationship but when I update-database I get the error "SupplyPointId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'SupplyPointId' is already defined."

I've tried removing the existing index constraint on SupplyPointAddress.SupplyPointId and that does not help. In the other table its the PK. Any comments really appreciated

```
    public partial class SupplyPoint
    {
        [Key]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

        public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }
        public string SPID { get; set; }
        public string SupplyPointName { get; set; }
        public int SupplyPointTypeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SupplyPointEffectiveDateTime { get; set; }
        public string GazateerRef { get; set; }

        public virtual SupplyPointType SupplyPointType { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("SupplyPointId")]
        public virtual SupplyPointAddress SupplyPointAddress { get; set; }


    }
    public partial class SupplyPointAddress
    {
        [Key]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SupplyPointAddressId { get; set; }

        public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }

        public string D5001_FreeDescriptor { get; set; }


        public string D5002_SubBuildingName { get; set; }

        public string D5003_BuildingName { get; set; }

        public string D5004_BuildingNumber { get; set; }
        public string D5005_DependentThoroughfareName { get; set; }


        public string D5006_DependentThoroughfareDescriptor { get; set; }
        public string D5007_ThoroughfareName { get; set; }

        public string D5008_ThoroughfareDescriptor { get; set; }
        public string D5009_DoubleDependentLocality { get; set; }

        public string D5010_DependentLocality { get; set; }

        public string D5011_PostTown { get; set; }
        public string D5012_County { get; set; }
        public string D5013_Postcode { get; set; }

        public virtual SupplyPoint SupplyPoint { get; set; }

    }


public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AscendancyCF.Models.SupplyPoint> SupplyPoints { get; set; }

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AscendancyCF.Models.SupplyPointAddress> SupplyPointAddresses { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplyPointAddress>()
               .HasOptional<SupplyPoint>(u => u.SupplyPoint)
               .WithRequired(c => c.SupplyPointAddress).Map(p => p.MapKey("SupplyPointId"));


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I moved the foreign key into SupplyPoint table so that the foreign key was being defined as SupplyPointAddressId in SupplyPoint. This worked and allows me to do SupplyPoint.SupplyPointAddress in resultant model

Answer (score 1):

Since you're testing with a real DB. Use some of the

**Database Initialization Strategies in Code-First:**

```
public class SchoolDBContext: DbContext 
{

    public SchoolDBContext(): base("SchoolDBConnectionString") 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SchoolDBContext>());

        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolDBContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolDBContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new SchoolDBInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

(Excerpt from [this site](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx))

It is pretty self explanatory.
If there's already a DB created, it just `DROP`s it.

Happy coding!

Comment: I've already got Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AscendancyCF.Models.ApplicationDbContext>()); in my Application_Start() of Global.asax

Comment: The error is when the Model is being re-created : One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

SupplyPointId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'SupplyPointId' is already defined.